# Error shows when searching and showing in binary files

Tags: netbeans

I am a highschool student and I am not that good at programing. I am having a problem with this method that intends to show the data of a certain client that is saved in a file. When I run the program, and test it on the interface, the text field only shows "Error en el archivo" And I don't understand why. Can someone help me please?

```
public void buscarclientes() throws IOException{
    try{
    RandomAccessFile archivoclientes=new RandomAccessFile ("clientesinf.dat", "rw");
    String nom =""; boolean existenombre=false; String nombre = ""; String email = ""; int tel=0; int cliente=0; long cantidadclientes=0; long tamclientes=94;
    cantidadclientes=archivoclientes.length()/tamclientes;
    nombre=this.Bclientes.getText();
    nombre=nombre.trim();

    while ((existenombre==false)&&(cliente<cantidadclientes)){
        archivoclientes.seek(cliente*tamclientes);


        for (int n=1; 1<=20;n++)
            nom=nom+Character.toString(archivoclientes.readChar());
            nom=nom.trim();

            if (nom.equalsIgnoreCase(nombre)){
            for (int n=1; 1<=30;n++)
            email=email+Character.toString(archivoclientes.readChar());
            email=email.trim();
            tel=archivoclientes.readInt();

           Mostrardatos.setText("Nombre:" +  nom + "\nEmail:" + email + "\nTeléfono:" + tel) ;

        existenombre=true;
        }
        nom="";
        cliente=cliente++;
    if (existenombre==false);
    {
        Mostrardatos.setText("No se encontró el nombre");

    archivoclientes.close();
    }}}
    catch (EOFException e){}       
    {
        Mostrardatos.setText("Error en el archivo");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The text field is showing "Error en el archivo" because it is running this line of code:

```
Mostrardatos.setText("Error en el archivo");
```

It looks like someone might have meant to put this in the catch block for

```
catch (EOFException e){}
```

however by putting the last '{}' at the end closed the catch block so that text
will always be set at the end regardless which errors are present.

My guess would be to change it to this:

```
} catch (EOFException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Mostrardatos.setText("Error en el archivo");
}
```

then if it still sets the error you should should get more detailed information in the output window of Netbeans.

Your code would probably be easier to read if you format it with `ALT-SHIFT-F`.